# build succeeded, .app in red,  (empty ios 1view template projects,Xcode 4.3.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, product, .app

I was given a build succeeded and the iphone simulator worked well after building and running, but the .app under the product group is in red.
I tried the following ways but none of them worked so far:

(1) changing the Build Locations to a custom location in Preferences and reopened the project

(2) code signing changed to iphone developers

(3)base SDK set to be iOS 5.1

No error came out throughout the building process and the actual .app files can be found in finder when the build location is set to be a custom folder (For the default ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData situation, the .app just can't be found in finder but the building went successfully as well, maybe it's hidden?),

So are the .app s found in finder the successfully built packages? But why can't xcode find them?

the .app now still in red, can any one tell me how I can turn the .app to a normal black? :-(
thx˜˜

Comment: It is normal to have .app in red

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your XCode project and restarting XCode?

Or maybe you have changed the product name in your build settings?